# Is there a way I can create a small graphic using vector drawing on a web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, vector-graphics

I would like to have an icon that resembles a ballot check mark which changes color depending on a data value. The icon would have very few lines in it.

Is there some way that I can create this on the fly rather than have to import an image. The reason is that I would like to be able to change the color of the icon or for example sometimes have the inside check mark of the icon appear in a color that is different from the outside. I'm not looking to use flash or anything fancy. Just hoping there is some way I can code this so it will work in modern browsers such as IE9 (if you can call that modern) and later.

Answer (score 4):

Make a white image(gif|png) with a transparent hole in it make the hole the shape of a tick.

Now set the image's background color to whatever you want.

---

Just thought of another way, there are two ticks in most modern Unicode fonts at 0x2714 and 0x2713

✓ - Thin Tick use `&#x2713;` in the html page

✔ - Thick Tick `&#x2714;`

I can't get SO to show these in colour, but you should be able to colour them as you need.

Answer (score 3):

[SVG](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/) is a W3C-specified format for vector graphics. [Internet Explorer supports it from version 9.](http://caniuse.com/#search=SVG)

Answer (score 2):

You could:

1. Use HTML5 canvas to draw the icon with JavaScript, or
2. Use a server-side script to generate a .png or .svg, using appropriate libraries for your language.